# How to get hold of the submitted checkboxes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, checkbox, razor-pages

I am using razor pages and this is what I am trying to accomplish

The user have list of rows, each row have a checkbox, the user select any number of checkboxes and click the button "approve selected". then my OnPostApproveSelectedAsync method should trigger and process only the selected rows. (code below is simplified)

```
<form method="post" style="padding-top:30px">
<button id="as" asp-page-handler="ApproveSelected" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                        <span class="fa fa-check"></span>Approve selected
                    </button>

<input name="approval" id="1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="approval" id="2" type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

in my razorpage model I have the following code that I can see gets triggered when I click the button but I don't know how to get access to the ids of the selected checkboxes

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostApproveSelectedAsync() {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check boxes

```
<input name="approval" value=1 id="1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="approval" value=2 id="2" type="checkbox" />
```

Your method.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostApproveSelectedAsync(int approval) {

}
```

The main trick here is to align the value in the `name` attribute with the model on the server side.

Comment: and how do I do that

Comment: @ThomasAdrian please take a look at my answer. the name attribute is `approval` and the property passed to the handle is named `approval` now if you put a break point in the handler you should be able to see the value that the html element has.Don't forget to put your `id` values in the `value` attribute.

Comment: I see, thnx, it worked, I needed to return an Array to get all selected values
 string[] approval